# How to get absolute position of shape in PowerPoint add-in?

Tags: c#, add-in, powerpoint

I'm writing plugin for MS PowerPoint using C#.
I need to get position each PPT shape in screen coordinates when presentation is running.
How it can be obtained?

I have position of presentation viewer window and have shape position relative to top-left corner of the slide. But I haven't position of the slide relative to pesentation viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each shape's .Top, .Left, .Height and .Width properties will tell you the position and size of the shape relative to the size of the PPT slide.

A few questions down there are some suggestions for getting the screen coordinates of the current slide show window.

[In a dual-monitor system, finding out on which monitor a PowerPoint slideshow is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233153/in-a-dual-monitor-system-finding-out-on-which-monitor-a-powerpoint-slideshow-is)

Once you have both of those bits, the rest should be a simple ratio calculation.

Comment: As I wrote before, I know how to get shape coordinates in slide and slide-viewer window position. But slide displays with saving it's proportions, so we have two black rectangles on the sides of the slide-viewer which fills unused space. Slide doesn't fill all space from the slide-viewer, it's top-left corner has some offset of slide-viewer's top-left corner and I can't find any way to find this offset.

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean.  The same answer applies, more or less, with a twist.  PowerPoint will make the slide as large as possible on the current display w/o distorting it and if the aspect ratio of the screen is different from the aspect ratio of the slide, PPT will add idenically sized black bars left/right or top/bottom.  Knowing the aspect ratio of the slide and of the screen, you can work out how wide or tall the black bars will be from that.