# Move the mouse pointer every 30 minutes

Tags: excel, vba

I want my mouse pointer to move automatically every 30 minutes.
I am writing the code in Excel VBA.
I tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/152969/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-set-cursor-position but it doesn't work.

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c19a5644-ef3b-447b-9b4f-5990c3595db7/move-the-mouse-pointer-from-excel-vba#f176fa28-373e-4147-9c49-aad89e20a419

Comment: Thanks. I have test it but is dosnt work for me :/ 

" compile error: user defined type not defined".

Comment: What exactly does not suit for you?

Comment: Did you insert the `Private dtmNext As Date` line at the top of the module?

Comment: Compile error: user defined type not defined". 
The error shows on first line "Hold as POINTAPI".

I´m insert this code:

Private dtmNext As Date

' Move cursor every 30 seconds
Sub Move_Cursor()
    Dim Hold As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos Hold
    SetCursorPos Hold.X_Pos + 30, Hold.Y_Pos
    ' Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    SetCursorPos Hold.X_Pos, Hold.Y_Pos
    dtmNext = DateAdd("s", 30, Now)
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor"
End Sub

' Stop moving cursor
Sub Stop_Cursor()
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor", , False
End Sub

Comment: Do you use VBA or .NET Framework (VB.NET)?

Comment: VBA. I´m just clicking at Visual basic from excel!

Comment: You need to define POINTAPI type in the module. See example below.

Answer (score 3):

Create new module with following code:

```
Private dtmNext As Date
Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (Point As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Long

Sub Move_Cursor()
    Dim Hold As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos Hold
    SetCursorPos Hold.x + 30, Hold.y
    dtmNext = DateAdd("n", 30, Now)
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor"
End Sub

Sub Stop_Cursor()
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor", , False
End Sub
```

Call `Move_Cursor()` to start moving the cursor every 30 minuts. To stop the automatic motion, use

```
Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor", , False
```

Comment: Thanks but it still does not work. Is there anything more that i need to have around the code? Right now i only have a blank sheet with your code in. The VBA says "Compilation Error: You can not define a custom type that is Public in an object module"

Something familiar? Thank you for the help, unfortunately it does not work :/

Comment: @G.Karlsson, try to add `Private` or `Public` modificator to the type definition.

Comment: get the same error message with public, and with private i get "Sub or function has not been defined"

Comment: @G.Karlsson, I have declared references to external procedures and now `Move_Cursor()` function works. Try to use updated code snippet from the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it almost works! When I run the code, the mouse moves, but when I check if it moves automatically, an error message will appear at the set time. (I changed it to be moved after 1 minute to test). The error message is: "You can not run macros. Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros are disabled." So maybe its something in the settings now..

Comment: @G.Karlsson, you are right. Save your wotkbook as *.xlsm and allow macros running in security settings. I tried to run proposed script on my computer and the mouse pointer was moved every 30 seconds (I had changed timeout settings).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the first answer, I just made a few updates (`PtrSafe` statement) and more friendly names

1-Create a module called "Mouse"

2-This code:

```
Private Type mousePos
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef p As mousePos) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Long
Private Function mouseGet(ByRef p As mousePos) As Long: GetCursorPos p: End Function
Function mouseSet(x, y As Integer): SetCursorPos IIf(x < 0, 0, x), IIf(y < 0, 0, y): End Function
Function mouseOffset(Optional x As Integer = 0, Optional y As Integer = 0)
    Dim Hold As mousePos
    mouseGet Hold
    mouseSet Hold.x + x, Hold.y + y
End Function
```

3-Code in another module to test only (Use only `mouseSet` and `mouseOffset`, if you need `mouseGet` just remove the `Private`, these are only examples of ways to call it

```
Sub mouseTest()
    Mouse.mouseSet 200, 200
          mouseSet 300, 300
    Mouse.mouseOffset 200    'y is optional
    Mouse.mouseOffset , 200  'x is optional
    Mouse.mouseOffset y:=200 'x is optional
          mouseOffset 200    'y is optional
          mouseOffset 200, 200
End Sub
```

The reason of the `IIf` is because a negative number will set the mouse to the other side of the screem

Comment: Actually, the `IIf` makes it not work when you have dual monitors. Using the mouseGet function you can see the coordinates are negative (at least for me) on my left screen. Perhaps a more proper way of doing it would be to get the count of screens then decide if negative is allowed? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241038/5159168

Answer (score -1):

It does work but, you need to create a module. Right click `ThisWorksheet-->insert-->Module`.

Only then it works.