# Open second excel workbook in other screen(monitor) VBA

Tags: excel, vba, monitor

I have two monitors. On the right-one I have my 1st macro workbook. How will I open the 2nd workbook on the left-one with the macro(VBA), which is placed in the 1st workbook. THX

Answer (score 0):

If you use this file on your own only and always in same cofig you could use some shortcut. 
 
`left` for primary monitor is = 0. If secondary monitor is on the left of primary then `left` for it will be some number < 0  (depends on resolution). 
 It secondary is on the right then `left` marking start of secondary monitor will be `left` + `width` of excel window (if it's maximized).

 
Assuming that secondary monitor is on the left 
 
This should work nice

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NewWbk()
    Dim Exl As Excel.Application

    Set Exl = New Excel.Application 
    'here you'll need to change to open your file instead of adding new empty file 
    Exl.Workbooks.Add 
    Exl.Visible = True
    With Exl.Application
        .WindowState = xlNormal 'can't move maximized window 
        .Left = -500 'should work on most resolutions
        .WindowState = xlMaximized
    End With

End Sub
```

But this is very unreliable solution and may not work properly in many cases. 
What you should do is to use API calls, check number of monitors, check on which monitor your app is visible and decide where to open new file.
 
Take a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241038/7049751)