# How to control the display position on multiple monitors

Tags: excel, vba, windows

How to display messageboxes or launch userforms, on the same monitor where Excel is running?

When using multiple monitors, Excel is displaying the messageboxes on the second monitor, and even if I open a new userform, it's opening it in the second monitor and not in the monitor where Excel is running.

Comment: Do any of these answer your question?  https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel+multiple-monitors

Comment: do you see any of them talking about the position of messagebox or opened userform when we have 2 monitors ? if yes, I can't see, so please tell me which one, and if not, it means the answer is no. thanks for trying to help

Comment: Look, also [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/launch-vba-userforms-in-correct-window-with-dual-monitors), please. It shows how to proceed (only) to show the form in the first monitor...

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot influence where a MsgBox is displayed - at least not in an easy way.

Also, dealing with multiple monitors and check on which monitor an Application is displayed is not an easy task. For a starter, you could have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7241038/7599798

However, a much easier way to display a form "above" Excel is to read the Application properties (`.Left` and `.Top`) and set the form properties accordingly.

If you show the form *modal*, you have to do this in the form code itself:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.Left = Application.Left + 100
    Me.Top = Application.Top + 40
End Sub
```

If you try to put this into the module code that calls the form, it will not work as the `Show` command will overwrite it:

```
Sub showForm()
    ' ********************************************
    ' This is not working!!!
    ' ********************************************
    Dim frm As UserForm1
    Set frm = New UserForm1
    With frm
        .Left = Application.Left + 100
        .Top = Application.Top + 40
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for trying to Help. Regarding the form position I will try it, but I think that UserForm_Initialize is better than the Activate ? 
Now for the messagebox how to do ? any idea ? I think it needs API, but don't know which ones. By the way, I don't need to know on which monitor it's running or information about that monitor aii I care about is to display the messageboxes of the Excel on the same Monitor where excel is running

Comment: You can use `UserForm_Initialize` if you prefer, but if you show the form a 2nd time (without creating a new Form object), the `Initialize`-trigger will not be executed again and if user moved Excel to a different monitor, form will stay on it's old position.  For the Message-Box: I think the much easier attempt would be to program a simple user form with a label and one or two buttons and use that.

Comment: You are right, it's better in this case to use Activate. Regarding the messagebox, the problem is that I am working on an existing projet, they asked me to fix all display probem, so I have to deal with the existing and as I saw in the code, sometimes they show userforms and some others messageboxes that's why I hope to find a solution for messagebox as well.